# Variables in memory

Tags: c, variables

If i have two variables a i b both int, and one pointer ptr that points to &b. If we would increment ptr++ like that it should be pointing at a,if i'm not wrong. I thought it's possible because when compiling a i b are in stack and b has 4 bytes less than a. But when i print that pointer in next line i only get address.
Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int a = 52;
   int b = 12;


    int *ptr;
    ptr = &b;

   printf("%d\n",*ptr);
   ptr++;
   printf("\n%d",*ptr);



    return 0;
}
```

but if i put printf("%d",&a); then last printf is printed good and it prints value of a
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int a = 52;
   int b = 12;

    printf("%d\n",&a);
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &b;

   printf("%d\n",*ptr);
   ptr++;
   printf("\n%d",*ptr);



    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain me why this happens?
Pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot increment a pointer to one object to point to another, unless the two are parts of the same array. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that about arrays,actually they are right behind another 4 bytes apart, and they will always bee only if i use more variables different types  then space between wont be equal.

Comment: Your first program never uses `a`, so the compiler is optimizing out the memory allocation and/or assignment. The second program uses it, so it gets memory assigned.

Comment: Which part of "undefined behavior" did you not understand?

Comment: @honeypot apart from a breach of the use of pointer arithmetic, one does not have to be right after the other. Suppose the memory alignment is 8 bytes? Or suppose they are placed in memory the other way round?

Comment: Look at pictures i think you will see my problem

Comment: @honeyPot: Look at the C standard and you will see your problem.

Comment: @EOF will do that,thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "I only get address". You're printing a random integer from memory.

Comment: @Barmar ok,but in 2. picture it clearly prints value of a , does it?

Comment: @honeyPot yes, it does. I was talking about the first program, where you said **But when i print that pointer in next line i only get address.** There's no address, just a random `int`.

Comment: I'll bet if you change the first program to use `volatile int a = 52` it will give the same results as the second one.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, so it has to be used to get memory assigned?

Comment: @Barmar: Why would you give such horrible advice?

Comment: @EOF I'm not giving advice, just explaining what's actually happening in the real world to cause the behavior he's seeing.

Comment: It seems to me that he's curious about what's going on under the covers.

Comment: @Barmar The behavior the OP is seeing is *undefined*. Declaring anything as `volatile` doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Thank you barmar for understanding me, i'm just trying out so i can see it how it works

Comment: @honeyPot: That is not a viable approach to C.

Comment: @EOF It changes the allowed compiler optimizations. It can't remove the assignment.

Comment: @Barmar: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.7.3 Type qualifiers 7 An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as described in 5.1.2.3.* Unfortunately, the rules of the abstract machine no longer apply, since the behavior is *undefined*. `volatile` is useless here.

Comment: @EOF This whole question is about implementation-dependent behavior, since it involves UB. So what the standard says about volatile is irrelevant, what implementations actually do is all that matters.

Comment: @Barmar The fact that you are unable to distinguish *implementation-defined* from *undefined*  explains a lot.

Comment: @EOF I understand the difference. When something is undefined, anything can happen. But it has to do *something*, and whatever it does is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is free to arrange local variables in any order it chooses on the stack.  In fact the C standard doesn't even mention a stack.  That's an implementation detail left up to the compiler.

Adding a seemingly unrelated line of code can result in the compiler deciding to place variables on the stack in a different order than it did without the additional code.  So you can't depend on this behavior when writing your code.  Doing so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which you have experienced.

Also, performing pointer arithmetic on variables that are not part of the same array is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C11 draft standard n1570:

> 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators
>
> 2
>
> > [...] See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
> >     information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> >     pointers.[...]
>
> 6.5.6 Additive operators
>
> 7
>
> > For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
> >     array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
> >     type of the object as its element type.
>
> 8
>
> > [...] If both the pointer
> >     operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
> >     element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> >     behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
> >     shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

After `ptr = &b;` and `ptr++;`, dereferencing `ptr` in `printf("\n%d",*ptr);` is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score -1):

You can't guarantee that `a` and `b` variables are stored anywhere near in memory, and it's plain unsafe to try to "travel" from one to another by pointer increments, and rely on the results. What you're doing is dwelling into the realm of undefined behavior, you shouldn't do that.